# Javamail SendFailedException

Tags: java, email

I'm trying to send and email with javamail api. The code is very simple but when I send the mail doesn't work. Show this error message:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send 
as this sender
```

The code is this:

```
public class Email {

    static Properties mailServerProperties;
    static Session getMailSession;
    static MimeMessage generateMailMessage;
    static String aInc = "scanner@impresia.es";

    public void sendEmail(String a, String c) throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        // Server propierties
        mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        // New mail
        getMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties, null);
        generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);
        generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(aInc));
        generateMailMessage.setSubject(c);
        generateMailMessage.setContent(a, "text/html");

        // Send Email
        Transport transport = getMailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("10.5.32.40", "scanner@impresia.es", "xxxxxxxx");

        transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());//generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

Please, could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try sending the mail after setting From address in the MimeMessage ?

Comment: Hello, I've could it. You're right. I put the address from and it's working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try sending the mail after setting From address in the MimeMessage.